# Pandas DataFrame.to_csv raising IOError: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Hi: I am trying to use the `Pandas` `DataFrame.to_csv` method to save a `dataframe` to a `csv` file:

```
filename = './dir/name.csv'

df.to_csv(filename)
```

However I am getting the error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './dir/name.csv'
```

Shouldn't the `to_csv` method be able to create the file if it doesn't exist? This is what I am intending for it to do.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

`to_csv` does create the file if it doesn't exist as you said, but it does not create directories that don't exist. Ensure that the subdirectory you are trying to save your file within has been created first.

I often do something like this in my work:

```
import os

outname = 'name.csv'

outdir = './dir'
if not os.path.exists(outdir):
    os.mkdir(outdir)

fullname = os.path.join(outdir, outname)    

df.to_csv(fullname)
```

This can easily be wrapped up in a function if you need to do this frequently.

Comment: `os.mkdir` creates only one immediate directory. If there are several levels of directories in the path that don't exist, use `os.makedirs`. However note that it throws an `OSError` if the leaf exists

Comment: @mz8i If an existing leaf directory is acceptable, `os.makedirs` can be called with `exist_ok=True` to avoid the error.

Answer (score 69):

Here is an alternative way to do this using the excellent standard library `pathlib` module, which generally makes things neater.

As explained elsewhere, `to_csv` will create the **file** if it doesn't exist, but ***won't*** create any non-existent directories in the path to the file, so you need to first ensure that these exist.

```
from pathlib import Path

output_file = 'my_file.csv'
output_dir = Path('long_path/to/my_dir')

output_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

df.to_csv(output_dir / output_file)  # can join path elements with / operator
```

Setting `parents=True` will also create any necessary parent directories, and `exist_ok=True` means it won't raise an error if the directory already exists, so you don't have to explicitly check that separately.

Comment: This was what is wanted, I also thought of creating directories recursively using the above implementation. But this is better and much simpler.

Comment: `pathlib` is such a dream! :D

Comment: @JKK You can do the exact same thing with `os.makedirs('long_path/to/my_dir', exist_ok=True)` - has the exact same behavior. However, nothing wrong with the object oriented `pathlib` approach if that's your cup of tea!

Comment: If I'm completely honest, this was partly just an opportunity to introduce people to `pathlib` 
...and yes, speaking as a Brit, it is very much my cup of tea! ☕

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Much cleaner and safer solution.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error when I accidentally added `file://` at the begging of the save path. Since search brought me here, might be also helpful to someone.

Comment: Silly! `pd.read_csv` has no problems with the `file://` prefix but for some reason `to_csv` does.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer of [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9219425/tim) if you have the whole file path in one string you can use this modified version:

```py
from pathlib import Path

output_file = '/tmp/long_path/to/my_dir/my_file.csv'
output_file_path = Path(output_file)

output_file_path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

df.to_csv(output_file)
```

By using the full path of the file in Path() it will point to that file, therefore we need to call .parent before .mkdir to not create a directory with the name of our file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was some permission issue. My os is Windows. There is a antivirus installed and I made that directory protected earlier. I totally forgot that. After disabling it, it worked fine. So, when you face any issue regarding this, do check if the directory is protected or not.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem but only for one filename. I save a lot files with diferent names in the same folder. And if I change this filename save the file.

I've a question, OS library have some chars reserved?

When I save "PRN.csv" in any folder take this error, if I change filename to "PRN5.csv" I can save it without errors.

Comment: wow! When I create this file manually in windows take a system error. So it is a OS error with some names.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35021799)