# Unable to store pandas data frame as a csv

Tags: python, pandas, sentiment-analysis

I am following this [tutorial](https://ahmedbesbes.com/how-to-mine-newsfeed-data-and-extract-interactive-insights-in-python.html) to retrieve data from news sites.

The main function is getDailyNews. It will loop on each news source, request the api, extract the data and dump it to a pandas DataFrame and then export the result into csv file.

But when I ran the code, I am getting an error.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from tqdm import tqdm, tqdm_notebook
from functools import reduce


def getSources():
    source_url = 'https://newsapi.org/v1/sources?language=en'
    response = requests.get(source_url).json()
    sources = []
    for source in response['sources']:
        sources.append(source['id'])
    return sources

def mapping():
    d = {}
    response = requests.get('https://newsapi.org/v1/sources?language=en')
    response = response.json()
    for s in response['sources']:
        d[s['id']] = s['category']
    return d

def category(source, m):
    try:
        return m[source]
    except:
        return 'NC'

def getDailyNews():
    sources = getSources()
    key = '96f279e1b7f845669089abc016e915cc'


    url = 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source={0}&sortBy={1}&apiKey={2}'
    responses = []
    for i, source in tqdm_notebook(enumerate(sources), total=len(sources)):

        try:
            u = url.format(source, 'top', key)
        except:
            u = url.format(source, 'latest', key)

        response = requests.get(u)
        r = response.json()
        try:
            for article in r['articles']:
                article['source'] = source
            responses.append(r)
        except:
            print('Rate limit exceeded ... please wait and retry in 6 hours')
            return None

    articles = list(map(lambda r: r['articles'], responses))
    articles = list(reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, articles))

    news = pd.DataFrame(articles)
    news = news.dropna()
    news = news.drop_duplicates()
    news.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    d = mapping()
    news['category'] = news['source'].map(lambda s: category(s, d))
    news['scraping_date'] = datetime.now()

    try:
        aux = pd.read_csv('./data/news.csv')
        aux = aux.append(news)
        aux = aux.drop_duplicates('url')
        aux.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
        aux.to_csv('./data/news.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
    except:
        news.to_csv('./data/news.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')

    print('Done')

if __name__=='__main__':
    getDailyNews()
```

Error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './data/news.csv'
```

I know that I have to give the path name in pd.read_csv but I don't know which path I have to give here.

Comment: The camelcase used in that tutorial, alone, is enough for me to suspect its validity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error would make sense if there wasn't already a `data` folder in the directory you are executing this program from.  There is a similar problem in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47143836/pandas-dataframe-to-csv-raising-ioerror-no-such-file-or-directory).