# Export csv to a particular folder using URL & file path in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, iis

I need to export my pandas dataframe as a csv in to the folder. My python solution is deployed on the IIS Server, where i get the "file_path" and the url, i use these two things to fetch or read my file.
This is what i did to read the incoming file.

```
from urllib.parse import quote

url = "http://20.9.6.11:8066" -- given
file_path = "file_upload/file_info/products/class1/file.csv" --given
incoming_file_path = url + "/" + quote(file_path)
df = pd.read_csv(incoming_file_path)
```

i am able to fetch or read my csv file successfully with the above code,But after my data get processed
i need to export that csv to some other folder, that i am not able to export. I did:

```
folder_to_export_path = "http://20.9.6.11:8066/file_info/products/processed_file"
clean_df.to_csv(r'folder_to_export_path+'filename.csv') # error
```

Comment: What error you get?

Comment: @ChandanKumar i tried &  the following error came : OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '20.9.6.11:8066/file_info/products/processed_file/filename.csv'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
folder_to_export_path = "http://20.9.6.11:8066/file_info/products/processed_file/"
clean_df.to_csv(folder_to_export_path+'filename.csv')
```

Reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923281/writing-a-pandas-dataframe-to-csv-file)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```py
clean_df.to_csv(folder_to_export_path+'/filename.csv')
```

or if using python 3.6+

```py
clean_df.to_csv(f'{folder_to_export_path}/filename.csv')
```

Comment: i tried the following error came :  OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'http://20.9.6.11:8066/file_info/products/processed_file/filename.csv'

Comment: @KRAJA is your code writing on the same server it's running from ?

Comment: Yes it's on the same server.

Comment: @KRAJA then remove the `url` part, you can write to the path directly like `clean_df.to_csv("file_info/products/processed_file/filename.csv")`

Comment: i tried your way FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: this error is coming. But when i tried clean_df.to_csv(" path_to_export") csv file has exported in my working directory with the name of "path_to_export"

Comment: @KRAJA yes that's because you need to go on your server and create the directories, make sure that `file_info/products/processed_file` exist in the server.

Comment: the file location should also access when i hit my API from outside server. For that you need to use the full url location.

Comment: @KRAJA yes, only do that for the writing part not the reading part

Answer (score 0):

Your last line has syntax error , try to correct it with the following :

```
clean_df.to_csv(folder_to_export_path+'/filename.csv')
```

Comment: i tried your code following error came OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'http://20.9.6.11:8066/file_info/products/processed_file/filename.csv'

Answer (score 0):

First of all, with [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) you need to pass a file path (or a file object).
So that makes your `folder_to_export_path='http://20.9.6.11:8066/file_info/products/processed_file'` invalid.

It should be
`folder_to_export_path = 'file_info/products/processed_file/filename.csv'` given that you want to export the CSV in `file_info/products/processed_file` directory.

Secondly, `to_csv` can create a file named `filename.csv` if it doesn't exist but it [**cannot create directories**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47143836/pandas-dataframe-to-csv-raising-ioerror-no-such-file-or-directory).

To create directories if they don't exist and then save a file you can do:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

folder_to_export_path = 'file_info/products/processed_file/'
if not os.path.exists(folder_to_export_path):
    os.makedirs(folder_to_export_path)

pd.to_csv(os.path.join(folder_to_export_path, 'filename.csv'))
```

That should work.

Comment: i tried your way, when i ran my code from my local, it created folder in my working directory which is somewhere else. And why not my folder_to_export_path = 'http://20.9.6.11:8066/file_info/products/processed_file/' because this is my actual file location where i want to export my df. It should access the file location when i hit my api from outside server.

Comment: Then specify absolute path of the directory like so `/home/kraja/file_info/products/processed_file/`.