# Problem using formatted string with pandas.to_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I can make a directory using a formatted string as the path.
This works:

```
directory = r'\{ticker}\options\{exp_date}\{cp}'.format(ticker=ticker, exp_date=exp_date, cp=cp)
check_path_exists(directory)

def check_path_exists(directory):
if not os.path.exists(r'C:\ticker_data'+directory):
    os.makedirs(r'C:\ticker_data'+directory)
```

But when I then try to export my dataframe to a csv it returns an error

```
df.to_csv(r'C:\{ticker}\options\{exp_date}\{cp}\{cp}.csv'.format(ticker=ticker, exp_date=exp_date, cp=cp))

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\MIK\\options\\2021-02-19\\calls\\calls.csv'
```

It is adding double slashes and I'm not sure why. I even manually created the csv file to make sure the entire path existed.

Comment: Hope [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47144000/6699447) helps

Comment: Your `check_path_exists` checks for `C:\ticker_data\...` whereas your `to_csv` skips that path and writes to `C:\MIK\...`?

Comment: Dur! I was looking for why it was adding two slashes, but that was the problem! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Chris answered my question in the comments. Thanks Chris.
I didn't have the full file path.